# Creating a Histogram in R from a data table in excel

Tags: r, histogram

Display the frequency distribution in a graph. Which type of graph is most appropriate?

I have tried many times and keep getting errors. I need the Frequency to be on the y axis with `ylim = (0,300)` and the number of convictions on the X axis.

```
> hist(convic$Number.of.Convictions ~ convic$Frequency, right = FALSE)
Error in hist.default(convic$Number.of.Convictions ~ convic$Frequency,  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

This is the desired outcome:
![enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried as [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a description of the errors you are seeing.

Comment: @sebastianmm i added the error. The code works if i try to make a stripchart but not with the histogram. >stripchart(convic$Number.of.Convictions ~ convic$Frequency)

Comment: If your data already has Frequency, Number.of.Convictions then it sounds like it might already be a histogram. (It depends on what `Frequency` is and what you expect the histogram to use as counts). If that's the case just plot it as is, don't try to call `hist()` on it.

Comment: @smci I tried making a graph using the `plot` command. The result is a graph with points. However, the graph I am attempting to recreate is a histogram. I added images above in the post. Do you what command I should use to recreate it? Thank you!

Comment: That plot looks good, you can use `barplot()`, with a red fill and black edge color. Also you'll want to add x- and y- axis labels, see the `xlab(), ylab()` arguments of `plot` commands. But please do post your data to make this an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
par(las=1) ## horizontal y-axis labels
with(convic,
      barplot(Frequency,names.arg=Number.of.Convictions,
      space=0,
      col="red", ## not exactly your colour, but close ...
      xlab="Number of convictions",
      ylab="Number of boys"
))
```

`with()` is a little trick so you don't have to write `convic$` as many times.

For what it's worth, part of the confusion may be that in the narrow technical sense, a histogram is supposed to represent an approximation of the density of a *continuous* variable, e.g. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) it

> ... is an estimate of the probability distribution of a continuous variable ...
>
> Histograms are sometimes confused with bar charts. A histogram is used for continuous data, where the bins represent ranges of data, while a bar chart is a plot of categorical variables. Some authors recommend that bar charts have gaps between the rectangles to clarify the distinction.[7]